# How to share cookies between subdomains in beego frameworks

Tags: go, beego

We intend to set cookie for *.1234tv.com in login.1234tv.com. However it does not work.

[image]

I have configure the container as below:

```
beego.InsertFilter("*", beego.BeforeRouter, cors.Allow(&cors.Options{
    AllowAllOrigins: true,
    AllowOrigins:     []string{"http://*.1234tv.com"},
    AllowMethods:    []string{"GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE","PATCH","HEAD", "OPTIONS"},
    AllowHeaders:    []string{"Origin", "Authorization", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Content-Type"},
    ExposeHeaders:   []string{"Content-Length", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"},
    AllowCredentials: true,
}))
```

and set cookie in controller like this:

```
this.Ctx.SetCookie("UNION_TOKEN", utoken, 3600*24*7,"/", ".1234tv.com",false,false)
```

Comment: I hope you're not using `this` as a variable name in Go...

Comment: I doubted this, the context here is for output in the source code .

Comment: "Does not work" is not a problem description. The screenshot clearly show that the cookie does get set.

Comment: On the cookies of chrome browser, I can not find the key UNION_TOKEN and it's value.@Volker

Answer (score 0):

The cause is set-cookie by response does not work. 
1.Since it is an across sites Ajax request, .withCredentials() can active the ability of set cookie by response.

```
$.ajax( {
   /* Setup the call */
   xhrFields: {
     withCredentials: true
   }
 });
```

2.On the side of response server, "`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`" must be "`true`" and "`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`" must not be "`*`" and "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" could be "`http://*.domain.com`".

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution to this question

```
beego.InsertFilter("*",beego.BeforeRouter,func(ctx *context.Context) {
        ctx.ResponseWriter.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        ctx.ResponseWriter.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
    })
```

if you want to send cookie in http,use "http://XX" instead of "*",or you can set "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" seprately in an API,like that:

```
beego.InsertFilter("*",beego.BeforeRouter,func(ctx *context.Context) {
        ctx.ResponseWriter.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        ctx.ResponseWriter.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
    })

func (c *ArticleController)AddArticle(){
    c.Ctx.ResponseWriter.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://XX")
}

$.ajax( {
   ...
   xhrFields: {
     withCredentials: true
   }
 });
```